# Ubuntu 23.04 add-apt-repository doesn't work

Tags: add-apt-repository, 23.04

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 23.04, when I run `add-apt-repository`, here is the error I got:

```
httplib2.error.ServerNotFoundError: Unable to find the server at api.launchpad.test
```

It seems that `add-apt-repository` is using some dev source root.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Observing same behaviour inside a Docker build that's locked to 22.04.

Comment: `add-apt-repository` works for me in 23.04, for example with `universe` in Ubuntu live and with `ppa:mkusb/unstable` in Ubuntu installed and live and in Ubuntu family flavours (e.g. Lubuntu). - Please edit your original question to show all details: the command line(s) and their output when things go wrong. The problem might be that you have upgraded, my tests were done in live systems and 'fresh installations'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost certainly just hit an outage on launchpad. It's back now, retry.

https://ubuntu.social/@launchpadstatus/110258422919682880

[image: launchpad status mastodon account]